# Array Access by key value

Tags: arrays

I am currently accessing array using:

```
address_components[0]['long_name'];
address_components[1]['long_name'];
address_components[4]['long_name'];
address_components[5]['long_name'];
```

However the array sometimes has information I don't want included in it that I cannot control which messes up my numbers.

```
   "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "2012",
            "short_name" : "2012",
            "types" : [ "street_number" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Wildwood Dr",
            "short_name" : "Wildwood Dr",
            "types" : [ "route" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "St Augustine",
            "short_name" : "St Augustine",
            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "St. Johns County",
            "short_name" : "St Johns County",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Florida",
            "short_name" : "FL",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "United States",
            "short_name" : "US",
            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "32086",
            "short_name" : "32086",
            "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
         }
      ],
```

But sometimes the results look like:

```
"address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "Amazon Fullfillment Center TPA1",
            "short_name" : "Amazon Fullfillment Center TPA1",
            "types" : [ "premise" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "3350",
            "short_name" : "3350",
            "types" : [ "street_number" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Laurel Ridge Ave",
            "short_name" : "Laurel Ridge Ave",
            "types" : [ "route" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Ruskin",
            "short_name" : "Ruskin",
            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Hillsborough County",
            "short_name" : "Hillsborough County",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Florida",
            "short_name" : "FL",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "United States",
            "short_name" : "US",
            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "33570",
            "short_name" : "33570",
            "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
         }
      ],
```

How can i access say the street_number long_name regardless of what position it is in?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 2):

That looks like JSON, so I'm assuming you're using JavaScript.

You do this the same way you tell a human being to do it.

"Here's how you see if a component has `"street_number"` as one of its types."

```
component.types.indexOf("street_number") >= 0;
```

"Now look for the components that have `"street_number"` as one of its types."

```
street_number_components = address_components.filter(function(c) {
    return c.types.indexOf("street_number") >= 0;
});
```

"Take the first component you find and extract its `long_name`."

```
street_number_components[0].long_name;
```

Put it all together:

```
(address_components.filter(function(c) {
    return c.types.indexOf("street_number") >= 0;
}))[0].long_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you talk about c# (or .NET) I would suggest using a Dictionary or maybe a List object.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not able to control the input data structure, you can always loop through it and test each element's type. Not sure what language you're in, but here's the idea.

```
for element in input:
    if element["types"][0] == "street_number":
         deal_with_street_number()
    if element["types"][0] == "long_name ":
         deal_with_street_long_name()
```